# Submit button refeshes page in firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, firefox

I have a form on a Cart Checkout page, the user will fill out the form and click a button to validate the form without leaving the page. once the validation is done a checkout button changes class and can be clicked.

this all works cleanly in chrome but firefox just refreshes the page when you click the validation button and the form empties. what do i need to change for this to work in firefox?

html

```
<form name="contact"id="contact" onSubmit="return checkform()" method="post" action="" >
<fieldset> 
<label for="firstname">Full Name</label>
<input onkeyup="checkform()" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Full Name"  class="required" id="first_name">

<label for="address">Address</label>
<input onkeyup="checkform()" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" class="required" id="address">

<label for="Company">Company</label>
<input onkeyup="checkform()" type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" class="required" id="company">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input onkeyup="checkform()" type="text" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com"  class="required email" id="email">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input onkeyup="checkform()" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx xxxx`" id="phone">
<button id="btn" type="button" class="validation">Validate</button>

</fieldset>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#contact').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        address: {
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: true
        },
    },
});

$('#btn').click(function() {
     event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#contact').valid()) {
        alert('Form is Valid, Please click Send Order');
        $("#btn-submit").removeClass("disabled");
        $("#btn-submit").addClass("simpleCart_checkout");
        $("#btn-submit").attr("href", "javascript:;");


    } else {
        alert('Please Complete all Required Feilds');

    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You need an argument here to reference the event object:

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `event` parameter as argument in the click handler

```
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
                           ^
```